# How to integrate Oracle SOA Suite and ADF TaskFlow security?

Tags: security, oracle11g, soa, oracle-adf

Do you have some hint, a reference, an example of how to integrate Oracle SOA Suite 11g (BPMN or BPEL) security with the ADF TaskFlow's security of the human tasks???

Answer (score 1):

You can always use onBehalfOf functionality to authenticate user on behalf of Administrator in your ADF application like this link http://biemond.blogspot.com/2011/10/working-with-human-worklist-api-and.html